# mysql insert select in same statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to simulate an auto_increment scenario during an insert without the field having the auto_increment property.  Here is the scenario sql statement:

```
insert into acct set id=(select @vid:=max(id)+1); select @vid;
```

Basically, I want the insert and select done at the **same** time so I can guarantee the value of vid is unique.

Comment: Why don't you use the auto_increment feature MySQL has? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: You're going to have concurrency headaches if you try to roll your own auto_increment functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the autoincremented value to be shared across transactions with guaranteed uniqueness, you should have a lockable singleton visible to all transactions which would hold the last unique value.

In `MyISAM`, it is stored in the table's metadata, in `InnoDB`, in a special memory object populated with `MAX(id)` on the first insert after the server startup.

Of course you can make your own (say a dedicated table with a single record), but, honestly, I don't see any benefits over the build-in functionality in such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into acct values ( (select max(id)+1 from acct), ... rest_of_vars );
```

Comment: How do I READ this value from the insert?  That is, I need to know the value of select max(id)+1 during the insert operation.

Comment: new - incremented - value will be inserted automatically so knowing value during is not needed. if after is needed <code>(select max(id)+1 from acct)</code>

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) to guarantee no one else will access the table :

```
START TRANSACTION;
insert into acct set id=(select @vid:=max(id)+1);
select @vid;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Can I do this in one SQL statement without transactions?  Basically I want to read the value of max(id)+1 during the insert operation.